# Response from ajax isn't outputting anything even thought I can see the JSON response in the network tab

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, jsonp

using jquery I am trying to get an JSON response from a REST server I set up to use in my application. The problem I am having is that when I try to print the json I am seeing nothing. However if I go to the network tab in the debugger. I can see the call I made, a 200 status, and the json request I desire. Why isn't it showing up when I try to print it in my application?

Here is the response from the server(http://localhost:8080/api/items):

```
[{"_id":"57d4469ad97bcc3faad65be0","name":"PS4","description":"Current gen game system","price":"400","date":"09-30-2016","taxable":"yes"}]
```

Here is the code I tried:

```
var url = "http://localhost:8080/api/items";

$.getJSON(url+"?callback=?",function(json){
    console.log(json);
})
```

I have also tried this but got the same results of the console outputting nothing:

```
var url = "http://localhost:8080/api/items";
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Now when I go to the network in my debugger I see this:

[image: Header]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
dataType: application/json
```

Or

```
var res = $.parseJSON(response);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: I get: "'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access." with the former and the latter still outputs nothing.

Comment: no error? could you alert something in success function before console.log?

Comment: I am not seeing any errors. When I tried to output something before the console.log in the success callback nothing was printed. I was able to print something before the ajax call though.

Comment: then it's a problem in api i guess? can you print something before the return response in your api file?

Comment: On the server? If so yes. I was able to print before sending the response. I also added an error call back and printed error.message and got undefined. Why am I getting that error when I can see the correct response in the network tab?

Comment: did you did exit after response in server? If its working fine then atleast it should do some alert in success function. Sorry man can't do more. 
Check this out: https://www.sitepoint.com/demos/ajax/